# Merge column values from two arrays to form an indexed array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, transpose

I have two arrays:

```
 $a = ['0' => 1, '1' => 2, '2' => 3]
 $b = ['0' => 4, '1' => 5, '2' => 6]
```

I want to create a new array like this:

```
[
    ['a' => 1, 'b' => '4'],
    ['a' => '2', 'b' => '5']
]
```

I have tried using `array_merge` and `array_merge_recursive`, but I wasn't able to get the right results.

```
$data = array_merge_recursive(array_values($urls), array_values($id));
```

Comment: I think you have to write your custom function to do what do you want, because you doesn't have any key like 'a' 'b' etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to apply [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with custom function:

```
$newArray = array_map('combine',array_map(null, $a, $b));

function combine($n){

    return array_combine(array('a','b'),$n);
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/okML7

Comment: This `array_map(null, $a, $b)` is interesting. Can you explain,please, how it works?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari  you can check this link for better explanation:- [Why does array_map() with null as callback create an “array of arrays”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615265/4248328)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$c = array_merge($a,$b)
$d[] = array_reduce($d, 'array_merge', []);
```

It will merge the two array and reduce and remerge it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` to approach this

```
$a = ['0' => 1, '1' => 2, '2' => 3];
$b = ['0' => 4, '1' => 5, '2' => 6];
$res = [];
$i = 0;
$total = 2;
foreach($a as $k => $v){
  $res[$i]['a'] = $v;
  $res[$i]['b'] = $b[$k];
  $i++;
  if($i == $total) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have an array `$ab = ['a','b']` and a array from your both arrays like this `$merged_array = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`. 
Now we can combine array `$ab` with each element of `$merged_array` and that will be the result we need.

```
   $first = ['0' => 1, '1' => 2, '2' => 3];
   $second = ['0' => 4, '1' => 5, '2' => 6];

   $merged_array = [];
   for($i=0;$i<count($first);$i++)
   {
        array_push($merged_array,[$first[$i],$second[$i]]);
   }

   $final = [];
   $ab = ['a','b'];
   foreach($merged_array as $arr)
   {
       array_push($final,array_combine($ab, $arr));
    }
    print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

All earlier answers are working too hard.  I see excessive iterations, iterated function calls, and counter variables.

Because there are only two arrays and the keys between the two arrays are identical, a simple foreach loop will suffice.  Just push associative arrays into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y1Idd))

```
$a = ['0' => 1, '1' => 2, '2' => 3];
$b = ['0' => 4, '1' => 5, '2' => 6];
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = ['a' => $v, 'b' => $b[$k]];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 4,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'a' => 2,
    'b' => 5,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'a' => 3,
    'b' => 6,
  ),
)
```

---

If we may interpret your requirements to not preserve the numeric keys, then this functional process is pretty slick. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/9R5sp)

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(int $a, int $b) => get_defined_vars(),
        $a,  // first array
        $b   // second array
    )
);
```